# Transferering Bitcoins from Coinbase to Binance

Tags: coinbase.com

I've heard people say that you should transfer your Bitcoins from Gdax to Binance. I bought my Bitcoins on Coinbase. Is there a way to transfer your cryptocurrency to Gdax without paying that overwhelming fee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear. Transferring funds between Coinbase and Gdax is free. You just have to sign up for an account with both.  See https://support.gdax.com/customer/en/portal/topics/939402/articles.  Gdax does have lower transaction fees than Coinbase.  You can easily transfer your BTC to Binance but there will be a mining fee associated with the transfer. Coinbase trades BTC, ETH, LTC, BCH. Binance offers many more altcoins to trade so unless you want to trade for these altcoins, I don’t see a big advantage for transferring your BTC to Binance.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link, it cleared up a lot for me.